# Error: W3 Total Cache Wordpress Plugin: CDN - Amazon S3/Cloudfront - Authorization Mechanism Not Supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, w3-total-cache

I have created a s3 bucket in US Standard Region which worked fine with cloud distribution in W3 Total Cache.

Then I created a s3 bucket in Mumbai (India, Asia) Region which shows authorization mechanism problem and says please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256. With some googling I came to know that the issue is with new regions as it requires V4 authentication while W3 Total Cache is only using V2 authentication mechanism, thus the issue.

I am trying to get a solution for this at W3 Total Cache WordPress Support forum without any answers. There were same problems earlier unanswered there.

I read issues/solutions here as well on this but couldn't get what should I do or add in config.php or other page to get this problem sorted. Would someone help a non-coder to get this problem rectified at WordPress?

Comment: Please add into your question (i.e. not in the comments) what you _did_ try? At present this is a bit broad, so it would help readers if you can narrow it down as much as possible.

Comment: @halfer i have added more information... will appreciate some help.